# How to get correct width and height for a canvas in react?

Tags: reactjs, canvas, ref

I am trying to use canvas in React. the following code is supposed to give me a black 800x800 canvas, but for some reason it ignores my dimensions and shows a 300x150 canvas.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class Sample extends Component {

    state = {
        canvasWidth: 800,
        canvasHeight: 800
    }
    canvasRef = React.createRef();

    componentDidMount() {
        const canvas = this.canvasRef.current;
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.fillRect(0, 0, this.state.canvasWidth, this.state.canvasHeight);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <canvas ref={this.canvasRef} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Sample
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set width and height as html properties:

```
   <canvas ref={this.canvasRef} width={this.state.canvasWidth} height={this.state.canvasHeight}/>
```

Comment: A note to the OP: Be careful with this, because even with the `ref`, the canvas will be cleared whenever the `width` and `height` are changed via a `setState()`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. @PatrickRoberts, what do you suggest as a better practice?

Comment: @skypen this is a good recommendation, just wanted you to be aware of that potentially unexpected side-effect. That behavior isn't unique to react, it's just that the `width` and `height` attributes are actually property accessors that also happen to clear the canvas when it resizes.